# Managing login with meteor iron:router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm creating a private area in my meteor.js app; using iron-router, I have defined a controller, used by every private route:

```
panelController = RouteController.extend({
    waitOn: function() {
        Meteor.call('panelAuth', function(error, auth) {
            if (!auth) Router.go('/panel/login');
        });     
    }
});
```

This allows you to enter only if you are authorized server-side by the method 'panelAuth';

it works quite good but if you try to type in the address bar of the browser the url of a private route without being logged in (or logged without needed privileges) for a while you can see the route rendering, and then you are redirected to login page;

I would like to show a loadingTemplate while the 'panelAuth' decides if you can access, and avoid to show the private route for a while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I'm sure you're aware, your invocation of Meteor.call is asynchronous. Your route is being rendered in the client, and then the asynchronous call returns, resulting in a re-route.

Have you tried using `onBeforeAction` ? This is what it is for. Although I suspect you'll still have a problem if you insist on using an asynchronous method call.

```js
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('login');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});
```

Since the client *can* see all of your templates (regardless of your security model), I'd focus attention on securing the publications. You could store a session variable on login indicating whether the user should be routed to the destination, and provide a more robust check on the data publication.

Here's an example meteor app, using iron:router, accounts-password and accounts-ui.

HTML:

```html
<head>
  <title>Login with Meteor</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  {{> loginButtons}}
  <p><a href="{{pathFor 'blah'}}">Blah</a></p>
</template>

<template name="blah">
  <h1>BLAH!!!! YOU SAW ME!!!</h1>
</template>

<template name="login">
  username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br/>
  password <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br/>
  <button id="loginSubmit">Submit</button>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```js
// default page
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('hello');
});

// secure page, requires login.
Router.route('/blah', {
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      this.render('login');
    } else {
      this.next();
    }
  }
});

// handle login, go to /blah if successful
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.login.events({
    'click #loginSubmit': function () {
      var username = $("#username").val();
      var password = $("#password").val();
      Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, function(error){
        if (!error) {
          Router.go('/blah');
        } else {
          alert("Errrrrrrrrrooooooorrrrr");
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```